# ActiveX component can't create object - 429

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have the following code and I am getting the below error. I am not sure what changed but this was working fine before a remote system upgrade. Below is the code. Can you someone help with a fix.

```
Sub Import()

Dim RW1 As Worksheet
Set RW1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("T_M") - this is where error occurs.

End Sub
```

Error - ActiveX component can't create object

Answer (score 0):

Your code and issue don't make sense to me, your `Sub` routine doesn't have a name or and `End`. It should look something like this:

```
Sub MySubname()

  Dim RW1 As Worksheet
  Set RW1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("T_M") ' this is where error occurs.

End Sub
```

The error you're getting doesn't match the code either, if you have a sheet called "T_M" this will work fine. If you don't then you'd get a `subscript` error. If you have a sheet that isn't a worksheet, you'd get a type mismatch error.

Comment: my code is with sub name a d end sub.sorry for not putting it there and now I have edited. I do have a worksheet "TM".

Comment: Is this all happening in Excel? How do you know this line of the code is where the error occurs? I'm not sure when creating an ActiveX object would ever be inferred from setting a worksheet object within Excel.

Comment: I am trying to run the code line by line and at this line error is throwing. Yes as I said it was working fine initially.